# Else command not working inside in make file

Tags: if-statement, curl, makefile, artifactory

I have this make file that checks if a file is present in a folder or not. If not that it should download that file from JFrog artifactory using the curl command. if the file exists then it should not do anything.

```
si_file := ms_auix
extract_path := C:\si
si_url := https://artifact.com/artifactory/aksi/SI/$(si_file).zip

.PHONY: download-si
download-si:
    @echo "Checking for $(si_file) in $(extract_path)..."
    @if not exist "$(extract_path)\$(si_file)" (
        echo "Downloading $(si_file) from Artifactory...";
        curl -u te14:cmVXluNkVJ -O "$(si_url)";
    ) else (
        echo "$(si_file) already exists in $(extract_path).";
    )
```

When i run this code the package is downloaded from the artifactory but the code still runs the else loop and i get this in the terminal

```
) else (
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, ) else (, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:11: download-si] Error 2
```

the if loop is working fine but why does it executes the else loop regardless. Can someone guide me here what is wrong with code?

Comment: In general, you can't write long multi-line Windows bat / cmd.exe scripts in recipes like this.  The syntax of cmd.exe is too anemic to allow this: it has special handling for newline characters that can't be emulated.  A POSIX shell script of any length can be written entirely on one line because the language syntax is robust enough to support that.  Windows batch files, not so much.  If you (a) must use Windows, (b) must use cmd.exe, (c) must write complex batch commands, then you should create a separate `.bat` file and invoke it from your makefile recipe.

Answer (score 1):

For multi-line commands you need to escape the newlines:

```
    @if not exist "$(extract_path)\$(si_file)" ( \
        echo "Downloading $(si_file) from Artifactory..."; \
        curl -u te14:cmVXluNkVJ -O "$(si_url)"; \
    ) else ( \
        echo "$(si_file) already exists in $(extract_path)."; \
    )
```

A possible culprit here being the lack of .zip file ending when checking for file existence.

HOWEVER, I can't get the parenthesis working, so I'll instead propose order-only dependencies to handle the conditional instead (albeit omitting "already exists"-message, also ignoring the .zip-file aspect):

```
# the target file
SI_FILE := $(extract_path)\\$(si_file)

# order-only dependency - create if not existing
download-si: | $(SI_FILE)

# target specific variable (repeat for other files)
$(SI_FILE): SI_URL := https://artifact.com/artifactory/aksi/SI/$(SI_FILE).zip

# rule for downloading the file (optionally add other files)
$(SI_FILE):
    echo "Downloading $@ from Artifactory..."
    curl -u te14:cmVXluNkVJ -O "$(SI_URL)"
```

Alternatively you can put the section in a script (with proper arguments):

```
download-si:
    .\download-si.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution:-

```
si_file := ms_auix
extract_path := C:\si
si_url := https://artifact.com/artifactory/aksi/SI/$(si_file).zip

$(extract_path)\$(sip_version):
    echo "Downloading $(si_file) from Artifactory..." 
    curl -u te14:cmVXluNkVJ -O "$(si_url)"   

.PHONY: download-si
download-si:
    echo "$(si_file) already exists in $(extract_path)."
```